# Qemu hangs in "Booting from Hard..."

Tags: 19.10, qemu

I have a ubuntu 19.10 and I wanted to run xv6 on it. I was able to run that until yesterday. Yesterday, suddenly when I typed `make qemu-nox` it doesn't start xv6 and just hangs in "Booting from Hardware...". I could run the project on other Ubuntu versions so the code doesn't have bugs. The following gif may help. Thanks[image]

Comment: Flag: "This is not a question"

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug as of the release of QEMU 4.2.0 that causes XV6 to bootloop.

This has been reported on QEMU's Launchpad ([LINK](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1860742)).

**EDIT 1: Please see xv6 github's pull request [#115](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/pull/115) for a workaround to the boot loop issue**